# Pare ZXing down to bare minimum

Tags: android, zxing

I am working on using the ZXing project to scan either a Data Matrix or QR code for our company's internal use and get the string back from the code.

I am doing this using an Android application, based off the source project on the site.

What I need from this is to throw out a large amount of the code to pare the project to a bare minimum necessary for this, as we are looking to just use it for the one purpose.

I have an application setup that uses a Surface Holder to get the QR code or Data Matrix in a picture. Is there a way to send that into the decoding in the core.jar file and get the string back?

Basically, I want to just decode my image without continuously scanning it, by taking one good picture and decoding it.

Any advice on a better way to accomplish my goal would work as well. This application should hopefully support back to API 11, but can adjust if necessary.

**EDIT**

To clarify, my main problem is getting an image to be decoded. I cannot seem to find how to call into the core.jar to decode the code once I have it.

Comment: What are you including? the core library is pretty small to begin with. You aren't including android/ are you?

Comment: The core library is fine, I just am having trouble determining how to send my data to the core library to get decoded. I started with the android/ and tried to determine where to go from there, but have been having issues finding the code I actually need from there.

Comment: Basically my application so far takes a picture of the code, and I cannot figure out how to properly get that to be decoded by the core.jar library.

Comment: You should use an existing installation of the ZXing (or compatible) app and call its scanner function through an intent. It will save you a lot of time and headaches. See here: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/ScanningViaIntent

Comment: I wish, but unfortunately that idea does not fit with what they want it to do. I just need to determine what to call from my application to get a picture of the code decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of stripping what is not needed before, develop your application and have [Proguard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/) remove unneeded bytecode at build time.

From Proguard description:

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. **It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes.** It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions.

However, check if this is compliant with ZXing license, [this wiki page contains all the relevant details](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/LicenseQuestions).

Comment: Yes that's a good idea and there's nothing about the license that would forbid that. The license still applies of course, just the standard Apache License.

Comment: I do like the look of this, but for my purpose it does not work. I am unsure of the code needed to do the project, as stated above. Once written, I may use this to cleanup though. Interesting to be sure.

Comment: I think that removing part before development it's not worth the extra time it would take. Extra code will just sit in a directory, occupying at most 1MB of disk space. If you manage dependencies using, say, Maven, you can also take advantage of automated download for fellow developers.

Comment: Your question is really not "how to pare down the library", yes, but it is also something you want to do. You do that with Proguard, and Proguard is built in to the Android SDK, so you should also use it.

Comment: Fair enough. I have marked this as the answer to what I asked, but will continue on my own and see what I can find for my other issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for what bit of the code does the decoding from an image, it's:

https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/DecodeHandler.java#77

You can make it simpler even. Of course you will be loading an image from elsewhere it seems but the call to the core is just about the same few lines.